# docker run CLI - blanks after \ produces `iinvalid reference format`

Tags: docker

I have copied part of a `docker run` command from a documentation. It produces `invalid reference format` error. After much trial-and-error I discovered a series of blanks after an 'end-of-line' `\`. like so (the blanks marked with * for visibility). Without the blanks docker starts processing (the incomplete command).

```
docker run -d --name radicale \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5232:5232 \
    --read-only \
    --init \****   
    --security-opt="no-new-privileges:true" \
    tomsquest/docker-radicale  -- not working
```

I cannot find a documentation which would explain the error message? Should this be considered a bug and fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backslash in shell (nothing to do with docker) is an escape character. The character after the backslash is treated differently. Normally a newline ends a command in shell, so to span multiple lines you escape the linefeed. Similarly a space separates arguments so if you want to pass a space as an argument itself you escape it.

The docker command line is order sensitive, and the first thing that isn't a flag or argument to the previous flag is parsed as the image name to run. Image names have different syntaxes and docker refers to all of these syntaxes collectively as references (you could pass an image id, remote image, without a tag, with a sha256 pin, etc, there are lots of ways to specify an image). When that parsing of the image name fails, you get an invalid reference format.

So in this situation, why did the image name parsing fail? Because the image name was   (one or more white space characters). The next error you should have seen is `--security-opt="no-new-privileges:true": command not found` which would clue you in to the `\` on the previous line not escaping the linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove strange chars after `--init` I marked as '`*`'

```
docker run -d --name radicale \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5232:5232 \
    --read-only \
    --init \******
****--security-opt="no-new-privileges:true" \
    tomsquest/docker-radicale
```

For example, try with:

```
docker run -d --name radicale \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5232:5232 \
    --read-only \
    --init --security-opt="no-new-privileges:true" \
    tomsquest/docker-radicale
```

And then, separate again with \